# Wordpress Contact form 7 add_filter() not working?

Tags: wordpress, validation, plugins, contact-form-7, add-filter

Can't seem to use add_filter for Contact Form 7.
Ultimately, I'm trying to use the code here to add custom validations: http://code-tricks.com/contact-form-7-custom-validation-in-wordpress/

But the add_filter calls don't seem to hook in where they are supposed to and nothing happens. Doing a simple ECHO test, I can see that the file is loading but no validation occurs.

Any idea what might cause this?

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text','cf7_custom_form_validation', 10, 2); // text field
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'cf7_custom_form_validation', 10, 2); // Req. text field
```

any specified cf7_custom_form_validation() function simply does nothing when form submitted. Even if I just have it echo some text or manipulate a variable. Nothing happens. The function doesnt' seem to get called.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the CF7 core code has been updated and some modifications are necessary to make custom validation work:
More details can be found here: 
http://contactform7.com/2015/01/27/contact-form-7-41/
and here:
http://contactform7.com/2015/01/06/contact-form-7

I'll give these a try and mark this as answered if it all works out.

Comment: This is the answer. I just can't accept it as such for another 23 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is the problem with add_filter in your case.This might be because the **incorrect id** used for **validation**. Check the **form id in the validation code** whether it is correctly used or not.

Comment: I don't think it needs any special form ID. If it does, what should it be?

I followed the directions exactly.add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'my_wpcf7_validate_text' , 10, 2 );
and in CF7 plugin: [text* fullName] .. nothing happens.

Comment: Did you select the check box written as Required Field? Select the checkbox  for all the field which you want to validate.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Turns out it was just an update to the core code that I wasn't aware of. All better now. see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the instructions on the following page are currently wrong - https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

The following code `$tag->name`

needs to read `$tag[name]`, since apparently $tag is an array now...